# UINavigationController background issue in UISplitViewController that is embed in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I want my `SplitViewController` to be embedded in `TabBarController`. I started with a Single View Application. Then I used storyboard to connect all controllers as shown on this [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7KzG.png)

The navigation works fine, but the problem is at the top and bottom bar background colour. I would like to use Translucent Black Navigation Bar and Tab Bar. For some reason, the background colour of Navigation Bar and Tab Bar in master view is grey instead of purple (colour of master view background). In detail view the colour is fine. Problem is clearly seen on this [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmYsu.png)

I tried to manually set the colour of `NavigationBar` but it didn't help.